# Troubleshooting an Exit Code 80131506 appcrash when marshalling an unmanaged array to a managed one

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I have a managed application that has to read binary data from proprietary files with an unmanaged third-party Win32-only DLL. I keep infrequent crashes where my application simply exits without any exception etc. In the application log in the system, I get the well-known exit code 80131506. Directly after this entry, I get an "Application error" where the faulting module is `clr.dll`.

In my managed code, where I have the control, I added lots of debug logging (Thanks, log4net) and found out that it crashes at this piece of code:

```
double* buf = new double[bufSize];
try {
    for(SliceIterator iter = numericSlice.begin(); valuesLeft > 0;) {
        size_t transferred;
        numericSlice.getValuesToArray(iter, buf, bufSize, transferred); // transferred is set to the number of values which were written to the buf array, iter is advanced automatically
        valuesLeft -= transferred;
        array<double>^ out = gcnew array<double>(transferred);
        System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy(IntPtr((void*)buf), out, 0, transferred); // <- crashes here
        valueReadCallback(domainId, channelId, out);
    }
} finally {
    delete buf;
}
```

The `SliceIterator` and `numericSlice` with its `getValuesToArray` method come from the unmanaged DLL, and what I want to accomplish is that I want to drag the contents of the `buf` array to the `out` array which is a managed one. The `valueReadCallback` is a `System.Action` that I get into the method where this code is called as a parameter. I have to do it this complicated because the vendor of the third party DLL implemented his own reference counting which goes wonky when I use it in managed code. So I have to stay in just one scope while I do all the nasty unmanaged stuff, collect everything and somehow blast it out to the managed side while still in there.

Now, my questions are: Am I doing this right? Does the `Marshal::Copy` really do a deep copy or just some "clever" re-referencing?

Comment: It is probably the nastiest exception you could ever get.  Invariably caused by native code corrupting the GC heap.  Well, you have some.  The exact location where it crashes is rarely the place where the corruption occurred.  It isn't detected until the GC collects the heap, that always happens later.  A good code review, unit tests, randomly commenting out code is the way to get somewhere.

Comment: I actually feared that. I have a lot of unit tests especially for the regions of my program where the interaction with the unmanaged stuff happens, but they all run fine. I disabled concurrent GC for the time being, as some people reported it helped them. Currently trying it that way. Next approach would be to run it off Visual Studio with "Enable unmanaged code debugging". I had a similar problem once where the problem was using an early `return` to leave a method that then freed unmanaged stuff in a `finally` block.

Comment: Turns out that disabling concurrent GC did not help, however I found a constellation where I can reproduce the problem on my development machine, and running it off VS with "Enable unmanaged code debugging" also reproduces it. I think this is a start.